# Apache FOP: XML-Node List to multi column table by XSLT

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to transform my XML with Apache FOP to a pdf. The transformation via XSL of my XML nodes into a table with 1 column just works fine. My List has 100 nodes and I'd like to display them in 10 rows by 10 columns.

This is what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CrossOffList>
  <Item>
    <id>1</id>
    <code>meisv</code>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <id>2</id>
    <code>6dbqt</code>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <id>3</id>
    <code>rgyjt</code>
  </Item>
  ... up to id=100
</CrossOffList>
```

This is my current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">

    <xsl:template match="CrossOffList">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="monospace">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"
                    page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" 
                    margin-top="0.5cm" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.5cm" margin-right="0.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" >

                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="0.75cm" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2cm" />
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="Item" />
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>

                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right" margin-right="2mm">
                    <xsl:value-of select="id" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="code" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this will produce a PDF file with only one column (actually there are two columns, one for the id and one for the code):

[image: FOP output]

What I'm actually trying to accomplish is an output like this:

[image: My Goal]

I've seen XSL examples, but they include `<tr>` and `<td>` in the XSL but FOP Apache won't process those solutions.

May anybody help me, with the XSL?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to put in each cell, a table containing 10 rows each as the following:

```
<fo:table>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <TABLE 1 HERE>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <TABLE 2 HERE>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            ...
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <TABLE N HERE>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Here is the stylesheet I used which groups items by 3 (you can just edit it to fit your requirement)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- set maximum rows to be grouped -->
    <xsl:param name="MaxRows" select="3"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="CrossOffList">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="monospace">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"
                    page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" 
                    margin-top="0.5cm" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.5cm" margin-right="0.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" >
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[position() mod $MaxRows = 1]"/>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="0.75cm" />
                    <fo:table-column column-width="2cm" />
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <!-- apply templates in a different mode to avoid infinite loop --> 
                        <xsl:apply-templates select=
                            ".|following-sibling::Item[not(position() > $MaxRows -1)]" mode="group"/>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item" mode="group">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="id" mode="group"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item/id" mode="group">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right" margin-right="2mm">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::code" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

working example [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/foprender/?save=17c79881-9bd8-4f7d-87fd-bc593b5a24ae-foprender)

Comment: Dear Joel , I could finally adjust the formatting. But now I have another request: I'd like to have a String1 above the table and on String2 below the table. The strings should be part of the xml file: </crossofflist><comments><comment1>this is the upper text</comment1><comment2>this text is rendered below the table</comment2></comments>. How would you modifiy your working example? Thx SiS

Comment: Can you modify your input XML?

Comment: Yes as I tried to show with my coment above. Feel free to adjust the xml to suppor the cross of list data (ids and items) and two comments (before cross of list and after cross of list). Thank you!

Comment: Please see the modified working example here (http://www.utilities-online.info/foprender/?save=fa2514b1-ee03-4be8-9118-ca1bd7691b14-foprender).